# Stackblitz : how can i execute a test using Angular?

Tags: angular, stackblitz

How can I execute a test scripts with Stackblitz using an Angular project? 
I see into the package.json a karma packages, so I am wondering if there is the possibily to test my components

https://stackblitz.com/edit/redux-in-actions?file=package.json

thanks
Andrea

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53122846?file=app%2Femployee.component.spec.ts)?  If so feel free to fork it and add your own data.

Comment: @dmcgrandle, the question is not how to create tests, its about how you make those tests run in Stackblitz.

Comment: How do you switch between running tests and your app though?

Answer (score 4):

One approach is using [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/) (which is a behavior-driven development framework) to run Angular tests in Stackblitz.

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jasmine-in-angular-vjmwru?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.spec.ts)

Brief description as [step by step guide](https://lukasznojek.com/blog/2019/05/add-jasmine-unit-testing-support-to-angular-in-stackblitz/)

Main steps:

1. Install Jasmine

- add Jasmine as dependency to stackblitz
- add file `/src/global-jasmine.ts`

  ```
  import jasmineRequire from 'jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js';
  window.jasmineRequire = jasmineRequire;
  ```
- Edit `/src/styles.scss`

  ```
  @import 'jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css';
  ```
- Add `/src/main-testing.ts file`

  ```
   import './global-jasmine'
   import 'jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js';
   import 'jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js';

   import './polyfills';

   // This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files
   import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';
   import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';
   import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
   import 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js';
   import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';

   // Requires 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js' and 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
   import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch';

   import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
   import {
     BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
     platformBrowserDynamicTesting
   } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

   // stuff to test
   import './app/app.component.spec.ts'

   jasmine.getEnv().configure({random: false});
   bootstrap();

   function bootstrap () {
     if (window.jasmineRef) {
       location.reload();
       return;
     } else {
       window.onload();
       window.jasmineRef = jasmine.getEnv();
     }

     // First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
     getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
       BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
       platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
     );
   }
  ```

2. Add tests `/src/app/app.component.spec.ts` e.g.:

   ```
   describe('Testing tests', () => {
     it('should succeed', () => expect(true).toEqual(true));
     it('should fail', () => expect(true).toEqual(false));
   });
   ```
3. Run the tests

   Use `"main": "src/main-testing.ts",` instead of `"main": "src/main.ts",` in file `angular.json`

Comment: ERROR in /Users/echelon-royer/Downloads/unit-testing-angular-apps/src/global-jasmine.ts (1,28): 

Cannot find module 'jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js'.

Property 'jasmineRequire' does not exist on type 'Window'.

Property 'configure' does not exist on type 'Env'.

Property 'jasmineRef' does not exist on type 'Window'.

Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Property 'jasmineRef' does not exist on type 'Window'.

Invalid 'reference' directive syntax.

Comment: It would be easier to just fork your working solution and work with that has a base

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Jasmine does not work on Stackblitz. If you are getting an error asking to install jasmine-core, even when installed, try downgrade to version 3.5.0. This worked for me, you can do this by adding the dependency on the bottom left: jasmine@3.5.0